# Why a function to be smooth requires more than one derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand the definition of smooth function like a function that is derivable infinite times.

If "smooth" means that the graph has not sharp corners it is sufficient only the existence of the first derivative.

Comment: In your words, smooth means that even the graphs of the derivativeshave no sharp corners.

Comment: Try riding in a car with continuous velocity but discontinuous acceleration, and see if you describe the ride as "smooth"

Comment: My question arises from a problem in computer graphics. If I plot the graph of a function I see that more derivatives the function has, more the graph is visually smooth. It is really more smooth if I look at the screen. If smooth is only a fancy name associated with a formal definition and the only important thing is the formal definition, how is it possible ?

Answer (score 10):

The word "smooth" is very over-used. It tends to mean "as differentiable as I need right now". In some contexts, it's used for $C^\infty$ (derivatives of all order exist and are continuous), in some for $C^1$ (first order derivative exists and is continuous). In some situation it could mean even more complicated things, like belonging to some Sobolev space.

Check the book you are using.

Comment: Without context, it is usually assumed $C^{\infty}$. Also I think his confusion is more on the English.

Comment: Well "piecewise smooth curves" often means piecewise $C^1$. It is very context-dependent.

Comment: It is context dependent. My main point is that his/her confusion is on trying to carry over the English definition of the word "smooth".

Comment: +1 for being the only one pointing out that the is not a  unique "smooth".

Answer (score 6):

In mathematics, definitions are made objective so that they cannot be understood in different ways by different people.

"Continuity" is quite opinion-based in its own right. Fortunately, results involving continuity do not rely on personal interpretation, because we make a covenant in advance to agree on what we mean by "continuity".

For the present question, the same idea applies.

A faithful suggestion is this: Familiarize yourself with the axiomatic thinking if you want to study mathematics seriously. Mathematics is not a real poem where the meaning of words are deliberately made open allowing different interpretation varying from person to person.

Comment: 1+, however how this solve the question?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up the layman's definition with the math definition. Smooth means infinitely differentiable, having corners or not has nothing to do with it.

Smooth means infinitely differentiable because "we say so".

Edit, as mrf says smooth can mean different things depending on contexts. But the point is that in each context it has a precise definition that only loosely has to do with an intuitive idea of "smooth".

Comment: So math definitions are completely arbitrary ? There is no link between the natural words of the definition and the formal statement

Comment: @Valerio In a way, you're correct. They aren't "completely arbitrary", you understand that having derivatives is sort of "smooth" so there is a motivation. However when doing math, this motivation is not at all helpful and worse confusing. In mathematics, a definition contains *all* the information. The word we use might actually have no link between the natural word, and the formal statement you are correct. There are "normal" topological spaces and "normal" subgroups and "normal" operators.

Comment: @Valerio Normal topological spaces are different than regular topological spaces. Although the two words in normal speech are almost synonyms.

Comment: "Smooth" does not always mean infinitely differentiable. What "smooth" means is context dependent. While differential geometers often use "smooth" to mean infinitely differentiable, analysts often use it to mean $C^{1}$. In the classroom or a textbook the author should be precise about what is meant.

Comment: As Gerald Sussman said, in mathematics, names are arbitrary. I can't find the original quote in English, but in French it goes something like: "En mathématiques, les noms sont arbitraires. Libre à chacun d'appeler un opérateur auto-adjoint un "éléphant" et une décomposition spectrale une "trompe". On peut alors démontrer un théorème suivant lequel "tout éléphant a une trompe". Mais on n'a pas le droit de laisser croire que ce résultat a quelque chose à voir avec de gros animaux gris."